# Trying call useQuery in function with react-apollo-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo

I want to call useQuery whenever I need it,

but useQuery can not inside the function.

My trying code is:

```
export const TestComponent = () => {
...
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(gql(GET_USER_LIST), {
    variables: {
      data: {
        page: changePage,
        pageSize: 10,
      },
    },
  })
  ...
  ...
  const onSaveInformation = async () => {
    try {
      await updateInformation({...})
      // I want to call useQuery once again.
    } catch (e) {
      return e
    }
}
...
```

How do I call useQuery multiple times?

Can I call it whenever I want?

I have looked for several sites, but I could not find a solutions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`useQuery` is a declarative React Hook. It is not meant to be called in the sense of a classic function to receive data. First, make sure to understand React Hooks or simply not use them for now (90% of questions on Stackoverflow happen because people try to learn too many things at once). The Apollo documentation is very good for the official `react-apollo` package, which uses render props. This works just as well and once you have understood Apollo Client *and* Hooks you can go for a little refactor. So the answers to your questions:

> How do I call useQuery multiple times?

You don't call it multiple times. The component will automatically rerender when the query result is available or gets updated.

> Can I call it whenever I want?

No, hooks can only be called on the top level. Instead, the data is available in your function from the upper scope (closure).

Your `updateInformation` should probably be a mutation that updates the application's cache, which again triggers a rerender of the React component because it is "subscribed" to the query. In most cases, the update happens fully automatically because Apollo will identify entities by a combination of `__typename` and `id`. Here's some pseudocode that illustrates how mutations work together with mutations:

```js
const GET_USER_LIST = gql`
  query GetUserList {
    users {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;

const UPDATE_USER = gql`
  mutation UpdateUser($id: ID!, $name: String!) {
    updateUser(id: $id, update: { name: $name }) {
      success
      user {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;

const UserListComponen = (props) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_USER_LIST);
  const [updateUser] = useMutation(UPDATE_USER);

  const onSaveInformation = (id, name) => updateUser({ variables: { id, name });

  return (
    // ... use data.users and onSaveInformation in your JSX
  );
}
```

Now if the name of a user changes via the mutation Apollo will automatically update the cache und trigger a rerender of the component. Then the component will automatically display the new data. Welcome to the power of GraphQL!

Comment: In case somebody still didnt get a full picture, here is quite nice example. https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/graphql-client-side-integration-with-apollo-hooks

Comment: Thank you for the description. I just do not get how this function could be rendered. The only way that a functional components being rendered are via its own state or props. But when I do console.log(props) it is empty but in the return it still re-render when the loading is false

Answer (score 62):

From apollo docs

> When React mounts and renders a component that calls the useQuery hook, Apollo Client automatically executes the specified query. But what if you want to execute a query in response to a different event, such as a user clicking a button?
>
> The useLazyQuery hook is perfect for executing queries in response to
> events other than component rendering

I suggest [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query). In simple terms, [useQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query) will run when your component get's rendered, you can use `skip` option to skip the initial run. And there are some ways to refetch/fetch more data whenever you want. Or you can stick with `useLazyQuery`

E.g If you want to fetch data when only user clicks on a button or scrolls to the bottom, then you can use `useLazyQuery` hook.

Comment: This answer should have been the accepted answer according to the title of the post. Let me upvote it.

Comment: not true that it (useQuery) can't be stopped ....there is a 'skip' option

Answer (score 7):

There's answering mentioning how useQuery should be used, and also suggestions to use useLazyQuery. I think the key takeaway is understanding the use cases for useQuery vs useLazyQuery, which you can read in the documentation. I'll try to explain it below from my perspective.

[useQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query) is "declarative" much like the rest of React, especially component rendering. This means you should expect useQuery to be called every render when state or props change. So in English, it's like, "Hey React, when things change, this is **what** I want you to query".

for [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually), this line in the documentation is key: "The useLazyQuery hook is perfect for executing queries in response to events other than component rendering". In more general programming speak, it's "imperative". This gives you the power to call the query however you want, whether it's in response to state/prop changes (i.e. with useEffect) or event handlers like button clicks. In English, it's like, "Hey React, this is **how** I want to query for the data".

Answer (score 6):

You can use fetchMore() returned from useQuery, which is primarily meant for pagination.

```
const { loading, client, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_USER_LIST);
const submit = async () => {
    // Perform save operation

    const userResp = await fetchMore({
      variables: {
          // Pass any args here
      },
      updateQuery(){

      }
    });
    console.log(userResp.data)
  };
```

Read more here: [fetchMore](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/pagination/#using-fetchmore)

You could also use useLazyQuery, however it'll give you a function that returns **void** and the data is returned **outside** your function.

```
const [getUser, { loading, client, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_USER_LIST);
const submit = async () => {
    const userResp = await getUser({
      variables: {
        // Pass your args here
      },
      updateQuery() {},
    });
    console.log({ userResp }); // undefined
  };
```

Read more here: [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#uselazyquery)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a reusable fetch function as shown below:

```js
// Create query
const query = `
    query GetUserList ($data: UserDataType){
        getUserList(data: $data){
          uid,
          first_name
        }
    }
`;


// Component
export const TestComponent (props) {

  const onSaveInformation = async () => {
  
    // I want to call useQuery once again.  
    const getUsers = await fetchUserList();
  }
  

  // This is the reusable fetch function.
  const fetchUserList = async () => {

      // Update the URL to your Graphql Endpoint.
      return await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/graphql?', {
      
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              query,
              variables: { 
                 data: {
                    page: changePage,
                    pageSize: 10,
                  },
              },
          })
      }).then(
            response => { return response.json(); }  
       ).catch(
            error => console.log(error) // Handle the error response object
      );
  }

  return (
    <h1>Test Component</h1>
  );
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternative that worked for me:

```js
const { refetch } = useQuery(GET_USER_LIST, {
    variables: {
      data: {
        page: changePage,
        pageSize: 10,
      },
    },
  }
);


const onSaveInformation = async () => {
    try {
      await updateInformation({...});
      const res = await refetch({ variables: { ... }});
      console.log(res);
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
}
```

And here's a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65309487/10088643) for a similar question.

Answer (score -2):

Please use
`const { loading, data, refetch } = useQuery(Query_Data)`
and call it when you need it i.e
`refetch()`

Comment: refetch() is not refresh or reload , refetch when parameter are same with before call load from cash not from server