# I need to call useQuery when handleChange function trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks

I need to call useQuery when handleChange function trigger if i make function and put useQuery in side function then its give error.
i need to do with diffrent way to crake this problem.
i already read this question link also  [Trying call useQuery in function with react-apollo-hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964838/trying-call-usequery-in-function-with-react-apollo-hooks)

but it's not fulfilled my case. please let me know how we can do?
and if it's not possible from useQuery through then what is an alternate solution ?

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [personName, setPersonName] = useState([]);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { metrics } = useSelector(
        state => state.metrics
    );

    const [metricsResp] = useQuery({
        query: fetchMeQuery
    });

    const { fetching, data, error } = metricsResp;
    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log('callled....')
            if (error) {
                dispatch({ type: actions.METRICS_API_ERROR, error: error.message });
                return;
            }
            if (!data) return;
            const { getMetrics } = data;
            dispatch({ type: actions.METRICS_DATA_RECEIVED, getMetrics });
        },
        [dispatch, data, error]
    );


    const [response] = useQuery({
        query: fetchQuery,
        variables: {
            "input": [
                {
                    "metricName": "ca",
                    "after": 1dsdv
                }
            ]
        }
    });
    console.log('response ', response)

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        console.log('callled....')
        setPersonName(event.target.value);
    }

    if (fetching) return <LinearProgress />;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                    {/* <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-checkbox">select metrics</InputLabel> */}
                    <Select
                        className={classes.dropdown}
                        multiple
                        value={personName}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        input={<Input id="select-multiple-checkbox" />}
                        renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}
                        MenuProps={MenuProps}
                    >
                        {metrics.map(metric => (
                            <MenuItem key={metric} value={metric}>
                                <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(metric) > -1} />
                                <ListItemText primary={metric} />
                            </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I got answer !!
just move useEffect into new component and render condition wise.