# How to restrict api call by useQuery to be called only once?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I've following component, which has a `date` variable. On each re render, `date` variable is getting updated. Now the the problem is as I've assigned date to a query variable, graphql fetches again and again infinitely. I have debugged the code and found apollo is Observing on `date` variable, when it is receiving a new value, it is to re.

```
import React from 'react';
import { getISODate } from '../../dateUtils';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { GET_EXPENSE_STATUS } from '../../queries';
import get from 'lodash/get';

const ExpenseStatus = (props) => {
  const date = getISODate(); // returns current date as ISO String Format
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_EXPENSE_STATUS, {
    variables: {
      date
    }
  });
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
  return(
    <div>
       {get(data, 'expenseStatus.value')}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I also tried with `useLazyQuery`. But no luck.

```
 const date = getISODate(); // returns current date in ISO String

 const [loadExpenseStatus, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_EXPENSE_STATUS, {
     variables: {
       date
     }
 });

 useEffect(() => {
   if(!called) {
     loadExpenseStatus();
   }
 }, []);
```

So, Is there any way, I can skip this Observer? I just want to receive the fetch call once.

Comment: possible duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964838/trying-call-usequery-in-function-with-react-apollo-hooks

Comment: you can also use `const [staticDate] = useState( getISODate() )` - fired once - as variables params (`date: staticDate`)

Comment: you don't need lodash to prevent undefined data .. just use `if(loading) return "loading";` before main return

Comment: Its not duplicate :)

Comment: Is there any alternative other than introducing a state variable? @xdam. I am aware of loading part. But I don't want that

Comment: state was 2nd alternative ... did you tested earlier one? ... return null (instead of any loading content)? ... or simple `{data && data.expenseStatus.value}`?

Comment: Yes, I tried variables: {       date: getISODate()     } but did not help

Comment: ... then no ... use state or useLazyQuery but define variables inside effect (loadExpenseStatus arg), no `!called` condition required

Comment: @GregBrodzik I'm affraid in this case (date=null) it wouldn't work at all ... no value preserved from earlier render (useState required for that in FC) ... or would be stopped until updated on external rerendering reason (no 'state update' to force rerendering)

Comment: @xadm you are absolutely correct.  Still believe your initial recomendation to freeze with useState is the best solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two solutions possible, 1st (initial value 'freezing'):

```
const [staticDate] = useState( getISODate() );
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_EXPENSE_STATUS, {
  variables: {
    date: staticDate
  }
});
```

or simple `const [date] = useState( getISODate() );` and `variables: { date }` ... when `date` with current value required in other places.

2nd one (when no 'date' value required in output/render):

```
const [loadExpenseStatus, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_EXPENSE_STATUS);

useEffect(() => {
  loadExpenseStatus( {
    variables: {
      date: getISODate()
    }
  } );
}, []); // called once
```

docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually

Comment: I was looking for the 2nd option. Thanks